# How to get an overview of all skills in my fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Is there a way to get an overview of all skills among all my dwarfs, either in vanilla DF or with a tool?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Dwarf Therapist](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Utilities#Dwarf_Therapist) is an external tool that lets you manage job assignments, gives you statistics, and lets you sort your list of dwarves by various criteria, including by skill.

This is a screenshot of a fortress population sorted by Farming skill, with the degree of skill indicated by the size of the box (or a diamond for legendary skill):

[image]

It accomplishes this by reading the data from the memory allocated to Dwarf Fortress, so it has to be matched to your version of DF. Thankfully, it's possible to [update its memory mapping for new versions of DF](http://code.google.com/p/dwarftherapist/wiki/MappingNewVersions) without waiting for a whole new version of Dwarf Therapist to be made available.

It's available for Windows primarily, with an experimental Mac OS X version also available.

Comment: I would never recommend playing Dwarf Fort without Dwarf Therapist running along right beside it.

Comment: Awesome tool. DF really needs an interface, even more than graphics...

Comment: It's all true.  Managing any more than like 10 dwarves without DT would be a nightmare.